# Codeanywhere and Phpmyadmin database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, codeanywhere

I am having a difficult time connection my codeanywhere to my phpmyadmin database. 
I am receiving this error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   '//username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

and my database connection looks like:

```
  <?php
     class Database {
private static  $dbName = '//database name here' ;
private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
private static $dbUsername = '//username here';
    private static $dbUserPassword = '//password here';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
       // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {     
        try
        {
          self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          die($e->getMessage()); 
        }
       }
       return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

I am wondering if there is a problem with my localhost and codeanywhere or if I simply inputted phpmyadmin wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Did you double check the connection parameters?

Comment: Codeanywhere is an editor (as per my understanding). So the connection problem is not with codeanywhere. The problem you are facing is with your web server and database. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes I believe there is a connection problem with phpmyadmin and localhost.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have a mysql user 'username'@'localhost' with `mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;` command. If you have an entry as username with host 127.0.0.1 then replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in your connection parameters. or else add a mysql user 'username'@'localhost' and try again.